# How to get a dynamic page html output in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

How to create a dynamic page in next.js html output?
I have a dynamic page for which no file is created after export. When I click on the links, it enters the page, but when refreshing the page, a 404 error was not found.
Or is there a way to define dynamic page links in node modules and server.js?

my code:

**[post].js**

```js
const Layout = dynamic(() => import('../../components/blogs/post'),
    { loading: () => <p>loading...</p> }
)

class Post extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Layout/>
        )     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you made the below files in your project?

[image: description image]

in this image, i made [uid].tsx under /pages folder. so i will render as per our **getStaticProps** and **getStaticPaths**

Without [uid].tsx we can not render our page at the respected route endpoint.

for more information please check [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages)

Comment: thanks but getStaticProps is used for static pages and cannot display new posts after export. I need dynamic pages for this reason. :(

Comment: so do you need dynamic page import?

Comment: yes, I do but But I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: Please refer to the below code:

`import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const PageLayout = dynamic(() => import('../page/layouts'));
<PageLayout>{children}</PageLayout>`

Comment: Please let me know if it is still not working:)

Comment: Thanks, I tested it but it gives a 404 error!

Comment: can you please share your code via jsfiddle? if possible then?
so I get more idea about it.

Comment: I updated my post, now it is correct with this code when npm run dev displays correctly but is not build.  > Error: Build optimization failed: found page without a React Component as default export in
pages/blogs/next.config